# Android how to read log, which created by glib

Tags: android, glib

now I'm using fluidsynth so file to play midi note，which write log by glib fun.

for example, g_vsnprintf(xxx);

```
#define FLUID_LOG                  g_vsnprintf

if(synth->verbose)
{
     FLUID_LOG(FLUID_INFO, 
               "noteon\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%05d\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%d\t%s",
               chan, key, vel, 0,
               fluid_synth_get_ticks(synth) / 44100.0f,
               (fluid_curtime() - synth->start) / 1000.0f,                  
               0.0f, 0, "channel has no preset");
 }
```

I want know android how to read this log?

Comment: Well.. where is that log?

Comment: I am sorry, I can't get the log info.
I just integrate fluidsynth so file in my project, and then I call some function。